# What's the differences? (command substitutions)

Tags: shell, command-substitution

1. `` printf "%s" `echo ../.. | sed 's/[.]/\\&/g'` ``
2. `printf "%s" $(echo ../.. | sed 's/[.]/\\&/g')`
3. `printf "%s" "$(echo ../.. | sed 's/[.]/\\&/g')"`

Answer (score 3):

<strike>As far as I can see, none, *in this particular case*, with the string `../..`.</strike>

Between the two second and third ones, there's not much difference with or without the quotes with *that particular input*, the string `../..`. But if the output from the command substitution contained white space or glob characters, there would be a difference, compare:

```
$ mkdir temp; cd temp; touch hello.txt
$ printf "%s" $(echo "foo * bar"); echo
foohello.txtbar
$ printf "%s" "$(echo "foo * bar")"; echo
foo * bar
```

See: [What's the right way to quote $(command $arg)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/443989/170373)

---

The one with backticks is a deprecated version of `$(...)`, and works differently wrt. quoting and escaping. Within the backticks, unlike with `$(...)`, one set of backslashes is used up for the command substitution, so you get a different result with that. (`\\&` turns to `\&`, which makes makes sed print the literal `&`, as `&` itself is special to sed and the remaining backslash removes the special meaning.)

See: [What's the difference between $(stuff) and `stuff`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/170373)

---

Additionally, Bash 5.0 had a bug/misfeature where a presence of a backslash was enough to have a string get treated as a glob, even if it didn't contain other, actual glob characters.

The result of the unquoted expansion in the second command would be treated as a glob, and `\.\./\.\.` would turn into `../..` in the same way e.g. `.[.]/.[.]` or `.?/.?` would. (The pathname `../..` should always exist, even in `/`. Of course `.?/.?` could match other names, too.)

Similarly, `failglob` might be triggered:

```
bash-5.0.3$ shopt -s failglob
bash-5.0.3$ echo $(echo 'xxxxxx\x')
bash5.0.3: no match: xxxxxx\x
```

(But just `echo xxxxxx\x` doesn't do it.)

See the [Bash-5.1-beta announcement](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-09/msg00019.html)   and e.g. [this bug report on the bug-bash mailing list](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-10/msg00021.html).

Comment: @they, yep, found the posts about that backslash issue on bug-bash, and [Stéphane added the links to the POSIX discussions on that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/694124/can-someone-tell-me-the-difference-between-these-three-command-substitutions#comment1316673_694146) to the other post